# Angular 6 ng serve failing after sometime in production

Tags: node.js, npm, angular6, pm2, forever

I m new to Angular. I have created Angular 6 application.

- Angular CLI: 6.2.1
- Node: 10.16.0
- Angular: 6.1.0

Started the application using command:

```
ng serve --ssl --host 0.0.0.0
```

It runs but after some time it stops. Below are the logs

> ```
> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
> 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
> 1 verbose cli   'run',
> 1 verbose cli   'start' ]
> 2 info using npm@6.4.1
> 3 info using node@v10.14.0
> 4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
> 5 info lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~prestart: MyApp@0.0.0
> 6 info lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~start: MyApp@0.0.0
> 7 verbose lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
> 8 verbose lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\MyApp\node_modules\.bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\opscode\chef\bin\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
> 9 verbose lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~start: CWD: C:\MyApp
> 10 silly lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --ssl' ]
> 11 silly lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
> 12 info lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
> 13 verbose stack Error: MyApp@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --ssl`
> 13 verbose stack Exit status 1
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
> 13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
> 13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
> 14 verbose pkgid MyApp@0.0.0
> 15 verbose cwd C:\MyApp
> 16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
> 17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
> 18 verbose node v10.14.0
> 19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
> 20 error code ELIFECYCLE
> 21 error errno 1
> 22 error MyApp@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --ssl`
> 22 error Exit status 1
> 23 error Failed at the MyApp@0.0.0 start script.
> 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
> ```

Kindly let me know how I can resolve this issue.

- Is it because `ng serve` is not production?
- Are there any other options except deploying on the webserver?
- Is there any other option to keep angular 6 running forever or any like any service?

Thanks

Comment: Your way to deploy angular application on production is incorrect. Please follow steps https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-deploy-an-angular-app-8db1af39f8c1 to deploy angular application on production.